# How do I use my IE browser settings to download a file in python/win32 api?

Tags: python, internet-explorer, winapi

How do I use my Internet Explorer browser settings to send http requests? I want to do this in python, but I think it'll require calls to the win32 api, so how do I do this with the win32 api?

I *could* manually fill out `http://user:pass@proxy` and use urllib, but asking the user for his password isn't acceptable, and hardcoding the proxy url isn't great either since it's set via configuration script in the browser settings.

Here's a solution, but it uses COM, and I'd rather be able to do it directly via the API.

```
import win32com.client
req = win32com.client.Dispatch('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0')
req.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', False)
req.send()
print req.responseText
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: For many parts of Windows, "the API" is the COM interface. That's true for MSXML, IExplore, and most of the other stuff related to IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
import _winreg
ie_inet_reg_data = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
proxyEnable =   _winreg.QueryValueEx(ie_inet_reg_data , "ProxyEnable")
proxy = _winreg.QueryValueEx(ie_inet_reg_data ,"ProxyServer")
```

this will cause problems if there is no proxy ... and only works for standard proxies not the autoconfig files things